# Как словить нужный хеш? Sammy js

Tags: jquery, javascript, маршрутизация, knockoutjs

```
self.search = function() {
        searchRes = $('#search_field').val();
        location.hash = "search" + "/" + searchRes;
    };     
Sammy(function () {
                    this.get('#search',':searchRes', function() {
                    this.param.searchRes = $('#search_field').val();
                        $('.inside').each(function() {
                            console.log(this.params);
                            if ($(this).text().search($('#search_field').val()) == -1) {
                                $(this).parent().addClass('blind');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }).run();
```

Работаю с  Sammy js. Не могу словить нужный хеш, в url он устанавливается, но через get не могу его распознать